# How can I use The PRU of BeagleBoard to do matrix multiplications for example?

Tags: python, microcontroller, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I am using PocketBeagle for the first time, I would like to know how can I use the PRU of beaglebone  with Python for Matrix multiplication for example?

Is it possible to run the code below,using PRU ?

Thanks in advance.

```
sigma = 2565/8192
mu = np.array(A)[3]
mu = mu[0]
#Aa = np.array((A)).T
Aa = A.T
Y = np.array((B/np.array(B)[3])).T
for i in range(10):
    N = np.exp(-(Aa-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))
    dNds =  N*(np.power((Aa-mu),2)/(sigma**3))
    dNdm = N*((Aa-mu)/(sigma**2))
    F = np.concatenate((dNds,dNdm))
    tmpM = F.dot(F.T)
    b0 = np.array([[(sigma),(mu)]])
    det = (tmpM[0,0]*tmpM[1,1]-tmpM[1,0]*tmpM[0,1])
    u = np.array((tmpM[1,1],-tmpM[0,1]))
    z = np.array((-tmpM[1,0],tmpM[0,0]))
    U = np.array((u,z))
    tmpMinv = (1/det)*U
    k = tmpMinv.dot(F)
    b = k.dot((Y.T-N.T))+b0.T
    sigma = b[0,0]
    mu = b[1,0]
    print(mu)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use **PyPRUSS**:

https://elinux.org/BeagleBoard/GSoC/PyPRUSS

https://bitbucket.org/intelligentagent/pypruss/src/master/

But it's an old software project, not currently maintained, that uses **PASM** which is no longer supported and communicates with PRUs over the older **UIO** interface.

I would strongly suggest to use C and/or assembler for the code to run on PRUs.

Follow one of the many tutorials available for the current versions of Beaglebone operating system:

[Coding for the BeagleBone PRU with C in 2019](https://www.element14.com/community/community/designcenter/single-board-computers/next-gen_beaglebone/blog/2019/05/14/coding-for-the-beaglebone-pru-with-c-in-2019)

and if your general application is in Python you can then call C/Assembler routines from there:

[How to Call a C function in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-call-a-c-function-in-python/)

Comment: PyPRUSS is not for running Python on Beaglebone, but for "PyPRUSS is a python binding/API for loading firmware and communicating with the PRUs easily"

Answer (score 0):

The PRU cannot do floating point calculations in hardware! Floating point would have to be 'simulated' in software.

It has a multiplication accelerator (kind of 'coprocessor'). You can more easily do fixed point calculations. The code you have shown has the exponential function in it - you would have to replace it with an approximal solution or a lookup-table.

Matrix multiplications are just several multiplications and additions combined, so nothing special about them.

Depending on the speed and accuracy, it is possible to run this on a PRU. Best use a C compiler, it has the math functions for floating point operations done in software already included.

The PRU is not very suitable for this kind of operation generally, but depending on your requirements (e.g. filtering a hardware sensor with max. 100 kHz update rate), it could work.